# why is Python not running all lines of my program

Tags: python

[image: image description goes here]

Hi, I just started learning computer science and am stuck. My program stops running after the user inputs where they would like to go on vacation. I can't seem to find any errors as to why the program ends after the line," location = input("Where would you like to go on vacation?")  ". I copy and pasted the program below.

```py
print("Congratulations, you have won a free vacation with airfare and hotel expenses paid!")

input("What is your name?")

location = input("Where would you like to go on vacation?")

print(location)

num_days = input("How many days will you spend on vacation, 4 or 7?")

expenses = num_days*100

print("The total expenses for food and entertainment will be" + expenses)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you've shared, it runs to completion when you run it on its own. Something is happening in your main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see any error in your code. Please double check your code.
Additionally, keep in mind that `input()` returns `string` by default. You have to convert it to `integer` using `int()` to use it in arithmetic operations  like addition,multiplication. Similarly, `str()` is used to convert an integer to string.
So, the last three lines need to be like this

```
num_days = int(input("How many days will you spend on vacation, 4 or 7?"))
expenses = num_days*100
print("The total expenses for food and entertainment will be" + str(expenses))
```